# Rails kaminari pagination with in_groups_of in activerecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pagination, kaminari

I'm hoping to use [in_groups_of](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/Array/in_groups_of) for my Activerecord query, but this doesn't seem to work well with pagination.

I want to do something where I want to split all the records by X, and view each part separately.

```
@document_texts = Text.where(active: true).in_groups_of(3)[0].page(params[:page])
```

EDIT:
It looks like in_groups_by isn't what I need. What I want to do is split 300 records say by 3 and be able to access the first 100, second 100, or third 100 with pagination.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could just use the [Kaminari per scope](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#the-per-scope) to accomplish what you looking for:

```rb
@document_texts = Text.where(active: true).page(params[:page]).per(3)
```

Comment: The per scope doesn't do what I'm looking for

Comment: Why not? If you really always want to divide *n* records into *x* chunks, you could just do ``page_size = Text.where(active: true).count / x`` and then use the result in ``.page(page_size)``.

Comment: I want to only display records 100-200 (20 per page) out of 600 total records.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try [each_slice](http://%20https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), something like following.

```
[16] pry(main)> a = (1..300).to_a
=>
[17] pry(main)> b = Kaminari.paginate_array(a).page(1).per(100).each_slice(3)
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
[18] pry(main)> b.each {|bb| print bb}
[1, 2, 3][4, 5, 6][7, 8, 9][10, 11, 12][13, 14, 15][16, 17, 18][19, 20, 21][22, 23, 24][25, 26, 27][28, 29, 30][31, 32, 33][34, 35, 36][37, 38, 39][40, 41, 42][43, 44, 45][46, 47, 48][49, 50, 51][52, 53, 54][55, 56, 57][58, 59, 60][61, 62, 63][64, 65, 66][67, 68, 69][70, 71, 72][73, 74, 75][76, 77, 78][79, 80, 81][82, 83, 84][85, 86, 87][88, 89, 90][91, 92, 93][94, 95, 96][97, 98, 99][100]=> nil
```